# Google On-device encryption Google Passwords

Tags: security, google-account, google

I recently decided to enhance my online security by changing all my passwords and activating Two-Factor authentication for most of the services I use. I updated my passwords in Google Password Manager and enabled on-device encryption.

After updating my Google Account password, I was automatically logged out of all my devices. However, when I tried to access my passwords in Google Password Manager, I received a message saying that I couldn't access my encrypted data on the device I was using. The message suggested that I should try using a device that I recently used to sign in to my Google account:

> for security, you can no longer access your encrypted data on this device. try again using a device that you’ve recently used to sign in to your google account.

What I have tried:

1. Checked the Web & App Activities settings on your Google Account and turned it Off and then On again.
2. Checked the cookies settings on your browser.
3. Confirmed that Sync is not paused in Google Chrome.
4. Cleared data in Google Chrome and turned Sync off, signed back in, and turned Sync on again.
5. Checked the Device Activity page on your Google Account and confirmed that Sync is On and not paused on the devices you recently signed out of.
6. Restarted my device and waited for bookmarks and passwords to load.

Despite trying these steps,I still cannot access my encrypted data on the device I am using, and I am looking for further help.

Comment: Hi, glad to hear that you have found the answer yourself! Just curious, did you use any assistance (e.g. AI Chatbot) while trying to fix this, particularly from "*Based on your message, [...]*"?

Comment: Hey Andrew,
Indeed I made use of an AI, which I only used to summarise what I did myself. Please forgive this mistake.

Comment: No worry, it's not really a big deal in this case, though a disclosure beforehand is encouraged because of [the referencing policy on Stack Exchange](https://android.stackexchange.com/help/referencing), and also the caveat that AI might not always be correct :)

Answer (score 0):

So I found my answer, there is a message saying that you need to complete Chrome's safety check:

> You’re using on-device encryption. To check your passwords, go to Password Manager on Android or use Chrome’s safety check.

After this you should be able to access your passwords again.